# $http.get returns the first page response in successive pagination requests(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am using angular $http.get for getting data from my api. Say my api name is `/api/endpoint`. I have implemented pagination with `/api/endpoint?start=1&end=5`. The pagination is for spaced at interval of say 5 items per page. Following is my snippet of request:

```
   $http.get('/api/endpoint', config) // config={params:{start:1, end:5}}
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log('in service', data.data.data); // please remember this line.
      return data.data;
    });
```

The first iteration seems fine. The response is data from the index 0 to index 4. But when I load next page:

1. the config is fine. `{start: 6, end: 10}`,
2. the request url seems fine. `apiUrl/api/endpoint?start=6&end=10`.
3. the response in the network debugger of the browser is fine `//data from index 5 to index 9`.
4. but in the `.then()` above and the steps after that, the data is always the data from `start=1&end=5`, regardless of anything. its always the first 5 data.

This is the weirdest bug I have ever faced and I dont know if anybody has faced it. But please do help me out here if you have and please dont downvote for the nature of the bug.

Comment: This is very strange...Do you have a working plunker?

Comment: not exactly. but i think it will work in the plunker. This is my office work, so i cannot disclose my project. and I am stuck in this stupid bug. @fikkatra I dont think stackoverflow is right place to ask such vague ambiguous bug.

Comment: Maybe it's because browser [cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)? Try add to config object `{cache: false, ....}`

Comment: could be browser cache .. clear that .. if using npm and a task runner then restart it ... PS nicely explained, upvote ... PPS you are logging data.data.data but returning data.data

Comment: I could not figure out the issue. It was not the cache issue either. I had to redo the whole thing. and it worked. Dont know what I missed. I guess I will have to delete the question. @StepanKasyanenko

Comment: thank you for the effort. I could not find the issue, i had to redo the module. @danday74